# I created a question but don't have control

Tags: support, migration

I created a question on stackoverflow, it got moved to superuser, and now I don't have control of it anymore.  I was not registered before it got moved, but now I can't add comments or edit the question, so its kind of pointless...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to have registered accounts on both sites and they need to be [associated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136940?tab=accounts#sort-top) for you to get control of it.

Otherwise there is no way for the system to distinguish between you and me.